# Getting Error code: 1064 while creating trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am creating trigger but it shows me following error :

```
        15:22:44    create trigger trigger3 before update on test.testdata    
    for each row  
    begin      
    if new.qty < 50 then         
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE VALUE '99999'       
    SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'An error occurred';       
    end if;    
    end;    
    Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SQLSTATE VALUE '99999'       
SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'An error occurred';       
end i' at line 8    0.000 sec
```

my trigger code is :

```
delimiter //

create trigger trigger3 before update on test.testdata

for each row 
begin

if new.qty < 50 then

    SIGNAL SQLSTATE VALUE '99999'
      SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'An error occurred';

end if;

end;

//
delimiter ;
```

[image]

Comment: What version of MySQL?

Comment: It's MySQL Server 6.0.

Comment: And using workbench `MySQL Workbench 5.2 CE` for accessing it graphically.

Comment: Wait a second I am putting Image of my installation directory then You ll decide.

Comment: @eggyal - have you seen the pic sir ??

Comment: It's likely v5.6.  Check by executing [`SELECT VERSION();`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/information-functions.html#function_version) or [`SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'version';`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_version)

Comment: @eggyal - I've removed my answer. But I don't think it's fair to downvote an answer for not taking into account a piece of info that wasn't present in the original question when the answer was posted.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario: As my (edited) comment said, earlier versions would have returned a different error.

Comment: @eggyal - It shows version : `6.0.0-alpha-community-nt-debug`

Comment: @eggyal - are you there ?? what happen ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MySQL 6.0 line was [discontinued in 2009](http://lists.mysql.com/packagers/418) (and never hit a production-level release).

Version `6.0.0-alpha-community-nt-debug`, as the name suggests, was a debug build of an alpha release—as such, it really was intended for contributors to the MySQL project to perform early stage testing of the new version.  It certainly should *not* be used in a production system.  Where on Earth did you come upon it?

Finding documentation for v6.0 is somewhat difficult, since it was long ago removed from the MySQL website.  There is however an archive on Oracle's website, where [the documentation for `SIGNAL`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/mysql-refman-6.0/sql-syntax.html#signal-resignal) states:

> This statement was added in MySQL 6.0.11.

Therefore you will not be able to use `SIGNAL` with this version of MySQL.  If you need to throw an error, you can execute a deliberately erroneous statement, such as calling a non-existent procedure:

```sql
CALL error();
```

However, if it wasn't obvious from what has been said above, you really should upgrade to a stable production-ready ("general release") version of MySQL server—such as v5.6.14 (which, despite the lower version number, is actually a much more recent release).

Comment: Thank You Thank You so much sir.. I don't know that I am using discontinued version. Otherwise I have MySQL 5.7.2.-m12 but I haven't install it. and it's in source package so I am also confused that how to install it ? Right now I am googling on it. But the good thing is that today I know that I am using too older version and I am shocked after knowing that , thank you so much. If you know how to install 5.7.2 version package then tell me because int's not native exe application to set up it.

Comment: @user2659972ღ: v5.7.2 is also an unstable, pre-production ("milestone") release.  I don't recommend using it in a production system.  v5.6.14 is the latest GA release, for which you can [download a Windows installer](http://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/MySQLInstaller/mysql-installer-web-community-5.6.14.0.msi).

Comment: Ok sir I ll use that version... I have that version size is 35.5 MB and also have source package of MySQL 5.6.13 that is of 234MB size. which one I use sir ?

Comment: @user2659972ღ: I admit that quite some time has passed since I last had a mathematics class, but I'm still pretty sure that 13 and 14 are different numbers.  Also, given that you just mentioned you didn't know how to build from source, why would you want a source package?

Comment: Sir version 14 is setup file that will be installed on double click but in version 13 I have package that contain folder something like bin,data,docs,include,lib, etc. then how to use those one, that I don't know.

Comment: @user2659972ღ: As I said, the link I provided was to the Windows installer (because you expressed a desire for a "native exe application to set up it") - simply run this program and it will do the rest.  If you want to build from source, or download binaries for manual installation, you can do so - but please [read the manual for instructions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/windows-installation.html).

Comment: Okay again thank you so much sir.. Thanx for wonderful support and help